# Alternative of master-details relationship on standard and custom object sult

Tags: apex, trigger, relationships, roll-up-summary

We have two object Opportunity(Standard) and Result(Custom),

Now many opportunity connected to result object and we want some of opportunity amount to result object(like rollup),

But

We can't create a master detail relationship in this scenario because in master detail you can't use standard object as master.

Is there any way we can archive it or we have to used trigger (we want to avoid custom development).

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to roll data up from a standard object to a custom object, there are many tools out there which are already written to do this job for you. By far the two most popular are **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)** and **[Rollup Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI)**. I always recommend the former, but know of many implementations where the customer was happy with the latter as well. Of course you can write your own custom code to do the same, but I recommend against it unless you are forced to do so. These tools are configurable, rigorously tested, and they represent the industry standard.

Note, I am not affiliated with either product.

Answer (score 1):

> We cant create master detail in this scenario b'coz in master detail you cant used standard object as master.

This is **incorrect**. You cannot create a standard object as detail. You always create a standard object as master in a [M-D relationship](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_considerations.htm&type=5).

> Standard objects can't be on the detail side of a custom object in a master-detail relationship.

For your use case you cannot create a M-D relationship as Opportunity is on the detail side here. You will need to look for alternative solution here.